# Can I have several fixed width layouts on one page?

Tags: css, layout, fixed

Ok, I know how to build fixed width as well as fluid and adaptive layouts.
I just wonder if I can accomplish this:
- Have fixed width layout for example 960px
- Which falls down to another fixed width layout, let's say 640px, if screen get's smaller than 960px. Thanks!

Comment: Yes...media queries. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

You have the ans in media queries, use this:

```
@media all and (min-width: 960px) {
    #content {
        width: 960px;
    }
}
@media all and (max-width: 959px) {
    #content {
        width: 640px;
    }
}
```

The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/piyushkmr/V4Q2m/1/